Marching Band Expectation
40 band members were evenly split into 20 band members that start marching on their left foot, and 20 band members that start marching on their right foot? These 40 members are then randomly sorted into 10 rows of 4 musicians. What is the expected number of in-step rows.
I am stumped by the solution to this question. So by the linearity of expectation the expected number of in-step rows will be the sum of expectation of each row. But what I don't understand is why the answer to the solution 10 * $E[X]$, where $E[X]$ = 19/39 * 18/38 * 17/37. I specifically do not understand why the expectation of each row is the same. Doesn't one row affect the next one?

Linearity of expectation does not require independence.  Try it with $4$ band members ($2$ left and $2$ right) in $2$ rows and you should be able to convince yourself the answer would be $\frac{8}{24} \times 2+\frac{16}{24}\times 0=\frac23$ by considering all $4!=24$ equally likely possibilities and that the expectation is the same $\frac13$ in each row.  So this is also $2 \times \frac13$ using linearity of expectation.

Is there a much more rigorous explanation why 1/3 in this case? I just can’t wrap my head around why the expectation for other rows are the same to the first one.

Counting the permutations is rigorous. Another argument is that if for a given permutation, swapping the first row with another row in any particular way gives a different permutation (bijectively), so the expectation for the first row must be equal to the expectation for each other row.

Is there a scenario where this falls apart?
